# How to make the POINT in a game of craps equal to a dice roll, using java and GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, boolean

Basically, I have a random number generator that generates two rolls of a die, and adds them together. The Variable M is equal to the sum of these two dice rolls. Some of the code in this set also applies to what the user sees, such as the Line.set, which displays the POINT. However, I am trying to set the point, and once the point is set, have the user win if the point is reached again later in the code.

```
if (M == 4 || M == 5 || M == 6 || M == 8 || M == 9 || M == 10) {      // Determines the POINT value, all of these numbers could be the point 


final int point = M;     // The point is equal to the value that M is when the POINT is rolled the fist time                                        

final int last = countr; // The last value is trying to determine which roll the POINT was set on, and if that same POINT value is reached later in the code, the user wins


        if (first == false) {  // If this is the first point value rolled,                                        

            Line.setText("The Point is now: " + point); // The Line Label tells the user what the point is                

            first = true; // To ensure multiple POINTs aren't set, this if statement will now always be true                                                

        }

        if (countr > last && point == M && first == true){ // states that if the user has rolled more times after setting the point, the sum of the dice is equal to the point, and the variable that states the point has already been set is true
                Line.setText("You Win"); // Tells the user they have won
                W = true; // Setting W to true, which means the user has won
            }  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm prepared to answer but I need you to clarify something for me. What exactly do you mean by

> However, I am trying to set the point, and once the point is set, have the user win if the point is reached again later in the code.

Specifically the part about reached again later in the code. Reached by what? For what?

Comment: Okay, so, in each round a POINT value is set that is either 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10. This number becomes what the user needs to roll again in order to win. So if a round is started, and the user rolls a 5, the user must roll another 5 in order to win.

Comment: I think your problem may lie with the "if countr > last" You set countr = to last and haven't chainged either variable. So where in the code will countr > last? If you did do this in another part of the code that you didn't show, please correct me so that I can further deduce your answer.

Comment: Okay, I guess that will probably be an issue, because I was trying to make it so last = the number of rolls when the POINT was reached, and countr = the total number of rolls. How would you make it so that if the POINT was set on the first roll, then last = 1 and countr = 1, and on the second roll last still = 1, but countr = 2, as the user has now rolled twice. Then, the program would be able to tell another roll had happened after the POINT was set, and the program would be able to see if the second roll equaled the POINT value, and allow the user to win